# Audio not working in Android platform with playn

Tags: playn

Is audio working in the android backend of playn?

I recently tried a demo I made, and it didn't play any sound.

This is happening just in the android backend, html and java are playing the sounds just fine.

I'm using mp3 files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Sounds work fine in my case for Android, but it doesn't work in Java - paradox.

My code:

```
soundTest = assetManager().getSound("sounds/test");
soundTest.setLooping(true);
soundTest.play();
```

I have audio files in path:

```
.../resources/test.mp3
.../resources/test.wav
```

Check if you dont add .mp3 od .wav to getSound method.
Check if you have files in subfolder /resources/ which is not writen in getSound method.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/PlatformStatus) they told, that sound implemented partially, it is real.

For me `PlayN.audio()` sometimes works some time doesn't, and some times it has invisible memmory leaks and crashes when you trying to close activity, so for PlayN Android part I implemented my own SoundPool (plays *.ogg). It's much more simply and stable than MediaPlayer.

Good working example [here](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html) and it works perfectly.

For Java Platform PlayN.audio() works fine.